# Convert elastic_transport.ObjectApiResponse to python response

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, flask

I am using python(3.9) with elasticsearch(8.5.3) and Flask(2.0.0).

When I use search api, response is returned as a elastic_transport.ObjectApiResponse type.

```
res = es.search()
return jsonify(res)
```

It throws error : `TypeError: Object of type ObjectApiResponse is not JSON serializable`

I converted `res` to dictionary using `dict(res)` and `return jsonify(res)`.
It worked but still I am not satisfied.
Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem switching to es V8:

add the `.body` to get the dictionary

```
res = es.search()
return jsonify(res.body)
```

Should do the trick

Comment: I still continued to use `jsonify(dict(res))`. Will keep your suggestion in mind too if faced any issue.